# creacion de un dominio virtual en windows con xamp

Tags: windows, xampp

tengo todo bien configurado pero obtengo errores al lanzar mi servidor, no entiendo en que estoy fallando, si alguien pudiera ayudarme a distancia con teamviewer se lo agradeceria mucho

he seguido los siguientes pasos
comprobar en el fichero de configuracion que la linea virtaulhost no este comentada

crear un nuevo dominio virtual en el fichero httpd-vhost.conf añadienlo las siguientes lineas para mi dominio virtual test.com

```
# Virtual Hosts
#
# Required modules: mod_log_config

# If you want to maintain multiple domains/hostnames on your
# machine you can setup VirtualHost containers for them. Most configurations
# use only name-based virtual hosts so the server doesn't need to worry about
# IP addresses. This is indicated by the asterisks in the directives below.
#
# Please see the documentation at 
# <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/>
# for further details before you try to setup virtual hosts.
#
# You may use the command line option '-S' to verify your virtual host
# configuration.

#
# Use name-based virtual hosting.
#
##NameVirtualHost *:80
#
# VirtualHost example:
# Almost any Apache directive may go into a VirtualHost container.
# The first VirtualHost section is used for all requests that do not
# match a ##ServerName or ##ServerAlias in any <VirtualHost> block.
#
##<VirtualHost *:80>
    ##ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
    ##DocumentRoot "F:/xamp/htdocs/dummy-host.example.com"
    ##ServerName dummy-host.example.com
    ##ServerAlias www.dummy-host.example.com
    ##ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-error.log"
    ##CustomLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-access.log" common
##</VirtualHost>

##<VirtualHost *:80>
    ##ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com
    ##DocumentRoot "F:/xamp/htdocs/dummy-host2.example.com"
    ##ServerName dummy-host2.example.com
    ##ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-error.log"
    ##CustomLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-access.log" common
##</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName test.com
DocumentRoot "F:\xamp\htdocs\local\basico\ejercicios-js\minitienda\"
<Directory "F:\xamp\htdocs\local\basico\ejercicios-js\minitienda\">
Order allow, deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost
```

>
luego he ido a mi fichero ubiado en la ruta C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc

```
# Copyright (c) 1993-2009 Microsoft Corp.
#
# This is a sample HOSTS file used by Microsoft TCP/IP for Windows.
#
# This file contains the mappings of IP addresses to host names. Each
# entry should be kept on an individual line. The IP address should
# be placed in the first column followed by the corresponding host name.
# The IP address and the host name should be separated by at least one
# space.
#
# Additionally, comments (such as these) may be inserted on individual
# lines or following the machine name denoted by a '#' symbol.
#
# For example:
#
#      102.54.94.97     rhino.acme.com          # source server
#       38.25.63.10     x.acme.com              # x client host

# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost

127.0.0.1 test.com
```

y cuando lanzo mi servidor me da el siguiente error

```
13:34:20  [Apache]  Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
13:34:20  [Apache]  This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
13:34:20  [Apache]  improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
13:34:20  [Apache]  Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
13:34:20  [Apache]  the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
13:34:20  [Apache]  If you need more help, copy and post this
13:34:20  [Apache]  entire log window on the forums
```

Comment: Este tipo de peticiones es mejor hacerlas por el chat. Si no editas la pregunta y especificas el problema, la pregunta será cerrada.

Comment: si es que  por mas que lo intento no logro conseguirlo, he seguido todos los manuales en linea y ninguno me funciona, si tu tienes un minuto libre para ayudarme lo cierro la pregunta

Comment: Edita la pregunta y muestra los errores para que te puedan ayudar.

Comment: Si te sale un error al iniciar Apache puede que sea porque otro programa esta usando el puerto 80. SI tu problema es este puedo ayudarte

Comment: antes de modificar los ficheros de configuracion no aparecia el error, no hay ninguna otra aplicacion corriendo en el mismo puerto 80

Comment: ¿Has probado a hacer `httpd -S` en el directorio bin de Apache para ver posibles errores de sintaxis en la configuración?

Comment: no, como se hace eso

Comment: @steven Para que le llegue el mensaje al usuario debes poner el arroba. `@NombreUsuario`.

Comment: No entiendo por qué se ha puesto en espera: **con los datos contenidos en la misma pregunta, he podido reproducir el error en local y he encontrado la raíz del problema y su solución**. Esta pregunta debería ser reabierta (luego si se cierra por otro motivo, es otra cosa, pero el problema definitivamente se puede reproducir)

Comment: Un problema está aquí (puede haber más): `Order allow, deny`. `Order` sólo toma una cadena como argumento (`allow,deny`, `deny,allow` o `mutual-failure`), al poner un espacio entre `allow,` y `deny`, Apache considera que son dos argumentos y falla. Habrá quien lo considere un fallo tipográfico, pero realmente yo no lo consideraría como tal porque los programadores pueden pensar que la `,` es un separador, cuando realmente es parte de una cadena de texto y así ser un error que le ocurra a más usuarios. Si la pregunta se reabre, lo pondré como respuesta. Mientras tanto, espero que te sirva aquí.

Answer (score 0):

Esto pasa porque el puerto 80 lo tienes ocupado. Prueba a cambiarlo por el puerto 8080.

1. Abres XAMPP y haces lo siguiente:

Configuración -> Apache(httpd.conf)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

2. Buscas en el documento lo siguiente (Puedes buscarlo con `Ctr+b`):
   Cambias donde pone 80 por 8080, osea le añades otro 80 tal que así `#Listen 12.34.56.78:8080`
   `Listen: 8080`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

3. Buscas más abajo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y lo cambias por `ServerName localhost:8080`

Creo que con esto será suficiente

Comment: eso tampoco funciona, porfa puedes entrar un momento en mi compu con teamviewe y arreglarlo tu mismo el problema